# zsh completion installations (autojump) - How to use them?

Tags: osx, zsh, autocomplete, homebrew, autojump

I just installed `autojump` and have `oh-my-zsh` installed in my system. I have included the log of the installation at the bottom of this post. Note that at the end it says:

```
zsh completion has been installed to:
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

What am I supposed to do with this information? How do I notify Zsh of this `zsh completion`?

Also, whenever I now login with my Zsh shell, I get:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/autojump/21.6.9/etc/autojump.bash:13: command not found: complete
/usr/local/Cellar/autojump/21.6.9/etc/autojump.bash:52: = not found
```

Why? How can I fix this?

```
$ brew install autojump
==> Downloading https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/archive/release-v21.6.9.tar.gz
############################################################################################################################ 100.0%
==> Caveats
Add the following line to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc file (and remember
to source the file to update your current session):
  [[ -s `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh ]] && . `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh

zsh completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

Comment: I take it you are on OSX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh-my-ZSH config file should have a line starting with `plugins=`, like this:

`plugins=(git gitignore autojump jira command-not-found zsh-syntax-highlighting)`

Whatever you put there is considered by ZSH to be an active plugin.

In case of AutoJump, [oh-my-ZSH Plugin Wiki](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins) states that:

> Enables autojump if installed with homebrew, macports or debian/ubuntu package.
>   This does not add any commands on its own.

Config file you are looking for: **`.zshrc`**

EDIT:

1. Note that some folks claim [FASD](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) is better, if autojump won't work for you, you may try FASD instead.
2. Thanks @Adaephon, added link to source of the quote and marked it's oh-my-zshell rather than pure ZSH.

Comment: As you quote from the [oh-my-zsh Plugin Page](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins), I guess you are using *oh-my-zsh*. `plugin=` is part of the *oh-my-zsh* configuration, which is a set of configuration files for zsh. It is not part of vanilla zsh and as the questioner did not mention using oh-my-zsh it will probably not help him.

Comment: Thanks @Adaephon I updated the OP to clarify that I use `oh-my-zsh` and am interested in solutions that may depend on it.

Comment: Thanks @Adaephon - I've updated my answer to mark this as it's truly a good point. <bows>

Answer (score 3):

Assumed that you use `zsh` shell, you have to manually add the plugin link.
See the instructions blew:

1. open `.zshrc` file

   `nano ~/.zshrc`
2. add `plugins=(autojump)` in the file
   [image]
3. re-open your terminal

Comment: It would have been less work for you and more useful to the reader to just copy the relevant text.

Comment: I want to explain it thoroughly, so I paste the whole image with a red frame.
how should I modify it to let it be more useful to readers?